# white thin horizontal line when including a png image into beamer focus theme

Tags: beamer

Im writing a beamer presentation, using focus theme 16:9 style. On the first slide I am trying to include a png image as a background image. It looks fine except there is a very thin white horizontal line on top. The rest of the slides are ok. If I dont include the image, everything is fine. I tried to resize or change the image in different ways but same thing happened. I tried as well to include a pdf instead of the png. Same thing:
this horizontal white line on top.

I tried as well the default 4:3 format instead of 16:9, but with the same problem.

See how I am including the png image:

```
\begin{frame}[plain]

    \makebox[\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{Images/c21.png}}

\end{frame}
```

Here you can see the result:

[image]

I was thinking this is a reader problem. But I can see the issue with different pdf readers. Im on MacOS 13.2.1 and using the latest TeX Live 2022. Any ideas what is this about? A bug in my code, a bug in some TeX package or !?

Thank you,
Stefan

Comment: Can you please add a compilable minimal reproducible example? If I guess enough code to make your code compilable, it seems to work fine https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHJOF.png

Comment: If possible also share the image, so we can check if maybe the image is at fault.

Answer (score 1):

The `focus` theme completely redefines the the `plain` frame. Amongst others, it "forgets" to actually make the frame plain by setting `\beamer@plainframetrue`. If you add this to the focus theme redefinition of the plain frame, the white line seems to vanish:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{focus}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{plain}[true]{%
    \beamer@plainframetrue%
    \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[focusplain]%
    \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[plain]%
    %
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[none]%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[plain]

    \makebox[\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}}

\end{frame}

    
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much. thats very true. this is fixing the original question

Answer (score -2):

I think I found the issue.

I was using this beamer template: "Focus" From here: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/focus-presentation. Basically I have downloaded the template and tried to just add on the 1st slide a 16:9 image.

If I just use the default beamer presentation everything is fine. If I use the focus template and try to add on the 1st slide an image. Bum. Thats it. You get the problem.

No matter of the image used. I might need to give up on the focus template or contact the author.

Update: I emailed the author of the focus template. Meanwhile I will switch and use the default beamer with the built in themes. Probable it is good to change the subject of the question to include this theme.

Thank you

Comment: I think it would be better if you would edit your question and add a small, but compilable text document that shows that you are using the focus theme. You could also remove unnecessary discussions of aspect ratios. If you see the same problem in 4:3, the problem is clearly unrelated to the aspect ratio and it seems odd to explicitly mention it in the title.